# Storing pictures in Android apps

Tags: android, bitmap

It is relatively straightforward to retrieve an image from the phone's camera app using an Intent, where that image is in the form of a Bitmap.

I don't know if this is an appropriate question for SO really but is it common practice to just save the entire bitmap as-is? Or do most people compress / resize it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tend to save it using Bitmap.compress, which will compress it for you.  Feel free to use PNG which is a lossless format, so no quality loss will occur when you reinflate it.

Of course if you're using an intent to get it from the camera, its usually saved to the file system already.  In which case that file is certainly compressed already.

Comment: So something like `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);` before saving it somewhere?

Comment: Looks like it needs an output stream. Normally I use `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(contentResolver, bitmap, title, description);` to pass the bitmap into the gallery. Is there a way to do this with an output stream?

Comment: So when you use that MedaStore call, it actually creates a shrunk down version of the image (a thumbnail) and only saves that to disk.  There's no need to shrink it further.  Compression of a bitmap nly exists when saving the image to disk, an in memory representation of a bitmap in a Bitmap object is always uncompressed.

Comment: Is there no way to save it to the Gallery uncompressed? (i.e. not shrunken down)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method as below:

```
   private Boolean saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = null;
    File file = null, image = null;
    Boolean save = false;

    try{

        bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);

        image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "", "/yourSelectedFolder/");

        if (!image.exists()) {
            if (!image.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: Folder Not Created!\nPlease Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Folder Successfully Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/yourSelectedFolder/","filename" + ".jpeg");
        save = file.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(bao.toByteArray());
        fos.close();



        if (save){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return save;
}
```